# How is it possible that Tarrlok couldn't Bloodbend this character?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

Huge spoilers for *Legend of Korra*.

In season one, the *Legend of Korra* is based on a bad guy who is a water bender and a Blood-bender who wants to take everyone's bending and make everyone equal.

When Tarrlok kidnaps Korra and locks her in a metal crate,  Tarrlok goes back to the city claiming that it was Amon's men who took her when it was actually a set up to leave Republic City. He get busted when he was witnessed blood-bending her.

When he goes back to where Korra is being held he runs into Amon and tries to Bloodbend Amon, however Amon isn't affected by Tarrlok's blood-bending at all.

Why is Amon able fight it and take Tarrlok's bending. How is that possible? **Why couldn't Tarrlok blood-bend Amon?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Amon himself is a powerful bloodbender

> Tarrlok:  I'm Amon's brother.  [Korra gasps. Cut to the camera panning
> across the bay of Republic City and a view of Aang Memorial Island
> with the bay shrouded in fog. Voice-over.]
>
> Tarrlok: **Amon is from the Northern Water Tribe.** [Cut to inside
> Tarrlok's cell looking outward at Mako and Korra.] **He's a waterbender
> and a bloodbender**, [Frontal shot of Tarrlok as he lifts his head up.]
> Just like I was.
>
> Korra [Surprised]:  What?
>
> [Korra and an equally shocked Mako glance at each other and back at
> Tarrlok. Mako takes a step forward to Tarrlok's cell.]
>
> Mako: Did you know this all along?
>
> Tarrlok:  [Cut to Tarrlok.] No, [Bends his head down.] not until after
> he captured me.
>
> [Camera cuts to a side-view of the entire scene.]
>
> Korra:    How did your brother end up becoming Amon?
>
> <sub>*—The Legend of Korra*: "Skeletons in the Closet" (1x11)</sub>

As such, he was able to use his own bloodbending skill to resist Tarrlok's attempt to bloodbend him. In fact, he was more powerful than Tarrlok, as shown by his ability to easily bloodbend Tarrlok back when they were children:

> Yakone: Noatak, go! [Noatak inhales, and Tarrlok struggles against the
> bloodbending. Tarrlok falls to his knees, and Noatak narrows his eyes,
> making him lean back.] Excellent. [Noatak bows to his father and frees
> Tarrlok.] Tarrlok, your turn.
>
> <sub>*—The Legend of Korra*: "Skeletons in the Closet" (1x11)</sub>

Comment: thank you so much for the time you put in to responding to me:)

Comment: @Kate_walsh24 - Basically he was able to bloodbend himself to resist Tarrlok.

Comment: BTW I saw you posted another question. I'm glad you've decided to stay.

Comment: Ya I saw you commented on that. Ya this site is pretty cool I love it. I'll prbly be here a while:)  thanks for commenting on my other post.

Comment: I tried up voting. It wouldn't let me:(. I'll keep trying.

Comment: I meant to put that in my other post. My bad but still is it any good @jonah

Comment: @Kate_walsh24 - I've heard that it is. I actually haven't watched it yet.